# Rails - Correct location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a Rails application set up on a 'api v1' structure:

```
module API::V1
  class MessagesController < AuthenticatedAPIController
```

And I have that Messages Controllers that belongs to a Topic,
something like:

```
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: 'json' } do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :topics do
        resources :messages, name_prefix: 'topic_', only: [:index, :create]
      end
```

I'm trying to set up the location but all I try I keep getting:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `API_V1_topic_message_url' for #<API::V1::MessagesController:0x6aa5f68>):
```

(Or similars).

Here's what I'm trying:

```
  if @message.save
    render json: @message, status: :created, location: [:api, :v1, @topic, @message]
```

I also tried:

```
 location: [:api, :v1, @topic, @message]
 location: [@topic, @message]
 location: [@message]
 location: [:API, :V1, @topic, @message]
 location: api_v1_topic_message(@topic, @message)
```

You name it! haha
What's the right way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** Routes:

```
          api_v1_topic_messages GET      /api/v1/topics/:topic_id/messages(.:format)                                               api/v1/messages#index {:format=>"json", :name_prefix=>"topic_"}                                        
                               POST     /api/v1/topics/:topic_id/messages(.:format)                                               api/v1/messages#create {:format=>"json", :name_prefix=>"topic_"}
```

So the answer is:

```
api_v1_topic_messages_url(@topic)
```

Comment: when you run `rake routes` on the command line... what does it *think* the route-path turns into?

Comment: @TarynEast I updated the question. So you killed it. Can you please transform your comment in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Can you try calling your module Api instead of API? Module Api::V1

Comment: Thanks Mike, problem solved by Taryn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `rake routes` on the command line... what does it think the route-path turns into?

I ask because there are often minor differences :)
In this case - both the routes you use needed the `messages` part to be pluralised.